# Возможно ли это? - object type="application/excel" data="app.xls"

Tags: html, excel

Можно ли сделать такой объект и чтобы он работал?

`<object type="application/excel" data="app.xls"></object>`

Может быть, я где-то допустил ошибку? Или нужен какой-либо плагин?

Если сделать это невозможно, то подскажите, где можно сделать такую же таблицу наподобие 'excel', в какой программе? Мне не подходит таблица `<table>`, сделанная в самом HTML, поэтому приходится искать другие способы.

Может, таблицу 'excel' можно как-то открыть через PHP или вообще Javascript?

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: <table> мне не подходит по одной очень большой причине. В общем, это долгая история.

Answer (score 1):

```
<object data="document.xls" type="application/vnd.ms-excel">
У Вас нет плагина Excel документов.
<a href="document.xls">Скачать файл</a>.
</object>
```

Попробуйте вот так.

Comment: Да только я не понимаю, как это вам может не подходить обычны <table>. Через него можно сделать так же, как и в икселе. Если нужны какие-либо фильтры - привет javascript.

Comment: К сожалению, не работает)

Comment: А может, на страницу можно вставить плагин Excel!?